# Adobe Animate CC

Tags: actionscript-3

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "Um1" to flash.display.MovieClip

Um1, Um2, Um3..... MovieClip Object in my Stage

```
var Um: Array = new Array();
for (var i: int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Um[i] = "Um" + Number(i + 1);
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, HitUm);
function HitUm(event: Event) {
  for (var i: int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(MovieClip(Um[i]).hitTestObject(car_mc.rabond_mc)) {
      trace(Um[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 4):

This line here:

```
Um[i] = "Um" + Number(i + 1);
```

is populating your `Um` array with a string value.   You later use that value like it's a MovieClip (which it isn't), so you get that error.  Most likely your `trace(Um[i])` line results in "Um1", "Um2" etc. when it should be "[Object MovieClip]"

Assuming you have instance names in the same scope you are trying to get references to, you can do one of the following.

Use [getChildByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()):

```
Um[i] = getChildByName("Um" + (i + 1));
```

OR use the current timeline (this) like a dictionary:

```
Um[i] = this["Um" + (i + 1)];
```