# Adobe Animate CC, For Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3

TypeError: Error #1006: hitTestObject is not a function.

car_mc, Um1,Um2,...... Movie Clip on my Stage

```
var Um: Array = new Array();

for (var i: int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
Um[i] = ["Um" + Number(i + 1)];

}

//------------------    
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, HitUm);
function HitUm(event: Event) {
for (var i: int = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    if (Um[i].hitTestObject(car_mc)) {
        trace(Um[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most probably **Um[i] = getChildByName("Um" + Number(i + 1));** instead of **Um[i] = ["Um" + Number(i + 1)];**

Comment: This is the same as your last question:  [Adobe Animate CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911429/adobe-animate-cc)  -  your missing the `this` before square brackets